# HtmlUnit - Dynamic Content not found

Tags: java, dynamic, htmlunit

I am not having any luck with dynamic content being returned in the HtmlPage object when loading this page: https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=5&strgroup=season&statgroup=1&startDate=2018-03-01&endDate=2018-11-01&filter=IP%7Cgt%7C0&position=P&statType=player&autoPt=true&players=&pg=0&pageItems=30&sort=22,1&splitArrPitch=&splitTeams=false

The "react-drop-test" div is empty. I am trying to find the anchor with the "Export Data" text so I can click it and get the content as a stream.

Any thoughts on what I can do to get the HtmlPage to contain the dynamic content?

Here is a sample of what I have right now. The anchors never return any elements.

```
    webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(jsTimeout);
    updateJSErrorListener(webClient);

    int thisYear = year;
    if (isEarlySeason()) {
        thisYear = year - 1;
    }
    String leftyURL = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaderssplits.aspx?splitArr=5&strgroup=season&statgroup=1&startDate=" + thisYear + "-03-01&endDate=" + year + "-11-01&filter=IP%7Cgt%7C0&position=P&statType=player&autoPt=true&players=&pg=0&pageItems=30&sort=22,1";

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(leftyURL);

    HtmlAnchor leftyAnchor = null;
    HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getElementById("react-drop-test");
    List<HtmlElement> anchors = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (DomElement anchor:anchors2) {
        if ((anchor.getAttribute("class").contains("data-export"))) {
            leftyAnchor = (HtmlAnchor) anchor;
            break;
        }
    }

    Page p = leftyAnchor.click();
    InputStream is = p.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
    List<List<String>> leftyCSV = readCSVFile(is);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: Updated with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another web page filled with strange js. So let me start with some general hints:

- do not change the default configuration if not needed (or if you do not know what effect this will have)
- because your page (or at least parts) are rendered by javscript you have to wait at some place

And finally: you need a newer version of HtmlUnit to get the job done because the javascript impl [misses one feature](https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/commit/f40a91fae39c1797731379746c0a07a2edead417) to get the javascript code used by this page working.

To get the new (SNAPSHOT) version you have these options:

- wait for the next release
- wait for the next snapshot build available from maven (will inform via https://twitter.com/HtmlUnit if this is available)
- wait for the build server (http://83.169.43.181/jenkins/job/HtmlUnit%20-%20Fast%20Build/) to be green again and then download the latest artifacts
- or fork the project on Github (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit) and build it yourself

With the latest code base this will do the job for you:

```
String url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=5&strgroup=season&statgroup=1&startDate=2018-03-01&endDate=2018-11-01&filter=IP%7Cgt%7C0&position=P&statType=player&autoPt=true&players=&pg=0&pageItems=30&sort=22,1&splitArrPitch=&splitTeams=false";

try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(50000);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    System.out.println("----------------");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    System.out.println(page.asText());                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

    HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getElementById("react-drop-test");                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    List<HtmlElement> anchors = div.getElementsByTagName("a");                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    for (DomElement anchor:anchors) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        if ((anchor.getAttribute("class").contains("data-export"))) {                                                                                                                                                                                                              

            HtmlAnchor leftyAnchor = (HtmlAnchor) anchor;                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

            Page p = leftyAnchor.click();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            System.out.println();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            System.out.println("----------------");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            System.out.println(p.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());                                                                                                                                                                                                           

            break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the details. I have been tied up with work and haven't had a chance to look at this. I will report back.

Comment: Inbetween i made a new snapshot available.

Comment: Thank you for making these changes. It's working for me. Would you care to share  high level what changes you had to make?

Comment: Have added the link to the github commit if you like to know the details.